# Concatenate table of two columns into a single string with 2 delimiters

Tags: t-sql

Let's say I have a table with two columns:

```sql
create table #counties(
state varchar(max),
name varchar(max)
)

insert #counties(state,name) values('Alabama','Autauga')
insert #counties(state,name) values('Alabama','Baldwin')
insert #counties(state,name) values('Texas','Adams')
insert #counties(state,name) values('Texas','Houston')
insert #counties(state,name) values('Wisconsin','Adair')
insert #counties(state,name) values('Wisconsin','Wood')
```

I'd like the result to be a single string like this:

```
Autauga;Baldwin^^Adams;Houston^^Adair;Wood
```

For each change in the first column, I'd like the `^^` delimiter, and for each change in the second column, I'd like the `;` delimiter.

I'm aware of the `coalesce` function but I can't figure out how to use it over two columns, not just one:

```sql
declare @c varchar(max)
select @c = COALESCE(@c + ';', '') + name from #counties order by state, name
select @c
```

This is just for a data load but I'd still like to learn how to do it elegantly with just a select, and hopefully without a cursor loop.

Comment: I voted this up because of this: *still like to learn how to do it elegantly with just a select, and hopefully without a cursor loop* Come into the bright light of set-based thinking! Get away from cursors and loops, which are brought into the world by the devil of procedural code :-)

Comment: Hi, beacuse you want to learn :-)  : I just added an example to achieve the same but with a clean XML approach. The biggest advantage was, that you can add any kind of additional information without breaking the concept.

Comment: @Shnugo, thank you. I was hoping the answer would work for N columns, but I didn't want to be too greedy with my question. Thanks for thinking recursively!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
With NamesPerState AS
(
    SELECT c1.[state]
          ,STUFF(
           (
            SELECT ';' + c2.[name] 
            FROM #counties AS c2 
            WHERE c1.[state]=c2.[state]
            ORDER BY c2.[name]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') AS names
    FROM #counties AS c1
    GROUP BY c1.[state]
)
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT '^^' + names
        FROM NamesPerState
        ORDER BY [state]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,2,''
)
```

### UPDATE

Just to show you, how easy this was with a clean and modern approach:

```
SELECT [state]
        ,
        (
        SELECT c2.[name]
        FROM #counties AS c2 
        WHERE c1.[state]=c2.[state]
        ORDER BY c2.[name]
        FOR XML RAW('county'),TYPE
        )
FROM #counties AS c1
GROUP BY c1.[state]
FOR XML RAW('state'),ROOT('counties')
```

The result

```
<counties>
  <state state="Alabama">
    <county name="Autauga" />
    <county name="Baldwin" />
  </state>
  <state state="Texas">
    <county name="Adams" />
    <county name="Houston" />
  </state>
  <state state="Wisconsin">
    <county name="Adair" />
    <county name="Wood" />
  </state>
</counties>
```

### UPDATE 2 Just for fun: the minimal output

```
SELECT [state] AS [*]
        ,
        (
        SELECT c2.[name] AS [*]
        FROM #counties AS c2 
        WHERE c1.[state]=c2.[state]
        ORDER BY c2.[name]
        FOR XML PATH('c'),TYPE
        )
FROM #counties AS c1
GROUP BY c1.[state]
FOR XML PATH('s'),ROOT('counties')
```

The result

```
<counties>
  <s>Alabama<c>Autauga</c><c>Baldwin</c></s>
  <s>Texas<c>Adams</c><c>Houston</c></s>
  <s>Wisconsin<c>Adair</c><c>Wood</c></s>
</counties>
```

And this would get your list back:

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<counties>
    <s>Alabama<c>Autauga</c><c>Baldwin</c></s>
    <s>Texas<c>Adams</c><c>Houston</c></s>
    <s>Wisconsin<c>Adair</c><c>Wood</c></s>
</counties>';

SELECT s.value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [state]
        ,c.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS [name]
FROM @x.nodes('/counties/s') AS A(s)
OUTER APPLY s.nodes('c') AS B(c)
```

Comment: This is one of the very best and helpful answers I've ever received on one of my questions! I do like xml better, but I'm working with a framework that's older than my son, and he's in college now lol. So, to move to 3 columns and beyond, I just take your first listing and make the select part of it the "with" part of a second `With`, then do a third below it, and so on, I get it.